# Not able to install any thing by using snap. Getting some mounting error

Tags: snap

**error: system does not fully support snapd: cannot mount squashfs image using
"squashfs": exec: "mount": executable file not found in $PATH**

Whenever I try to install any application by using snap getting this error. And also already installed application are not opening.

And few application have been removed automatically even I am not able to access my settings.

Comment: You've provided no base OS/release details